# How to print data of join query which are stored in Viewbag in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to display data from 2 different tables which are stored in `ViewBag` at view side but I'm unable to print the data, I get an error

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

The code at controller side

```
public ActionResult Packages()
{
    int Prov_id = 1;

    using (var db = new DataContex())
    {
        ViewBag.pack = db.Packages.Where(x => x.ProviderId == Prov_id).ToList();

        ViewBag.service = db.GroupServices.Join(db.PackageServices,
                gs => gs.ServiceId,
                ps => ps.ServiceId,
                (gs, ps) => new
                {
                    name = gs.ServiceName
                })
                .ToList();

    return View();
}
```

View markup:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.pack)
{
    <div class="col-md-6 bg-white mt-3">
        <div class="card border package-grid p-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="hidden" />
                    <h4 class="font-weight-bold py-2">@item.PackageName</h4>
                    @foreach (var item1 in ViewBag.service)
                    {
                        <h6 class="py-1">@item1.Name</h6>
                    }
                    <p class="py-3">@item.PackageDescription</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
                    <p><strike> Rs. @item.PackagePrice</strike> <span>Rs. @item.PackageOfferPrice</span> </p>
                    <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Remove</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you created `ViewBag.service` you have created `anonymous` object with `property` as `name` with `n` as `LowerCase` and at `view` side you are trying to use `@item.Name` as `N` as `UpperCase`.

Correct the property name and it will work.

Comment: i tries with @item.Name but having same error "object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'"

Comment: You need to try with `@item.name`.